# How to change VIMRUNTIME directory after build from sources

Tags: vim

How can I change $VIM and $VIMRUNTIME directory after building it from sources? It seems both directory always follow vim.exe and gvim.exe directory.

**update**: I built it in windows 8.1 x64 with MinGW32.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you do a proper installation, the runtime should be next to the Vim executables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
/usr/share/vim/vim74
:let $VIMRUNTIME="/tmp"
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
/tmp
```

Or add to `.vimrc`:

```
let $VIMRUNTIME="/tmp"
```

Comment: Vim can't remember that. It reset when vim closed.

Comment: You can put that to `.vimrc`.

Comment: That's my point. I want to put `.vimrc` file in separate directory from it's bin file.

Comment: No problem. Leave the default `.vimrc` with the `$VIMRUNTIME` setting and add a second line `so /path/to/other/vimrc`.